# Looking for link to Delphi Developer Debate webinar about 'goto' and 'with' statements

Tags: delphi

Recently, an Embarcadero webinar was advertised (for late July) that was to cover current practice on `goto` and `with` statements in Delphi. I missed it (impractical time zone).

It was claimed that the recording would appear (or be linked) somewhere on the Embarcadero website within "a couple of days", but I haven't been able to find any such link.

Can anyone in the Delphi community point me at it - or let me know if it is still to be uploaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the replay isn't available yet, but the slides are:

https://blogs.embarcadero.com/delphi-developer-debate-with-goto-label-sllides-and-replay/

The above address should have a link to the replay when it becomes available.

When it arrives, I would expect it to be here:

https://www.youtube.com/c/EmbarcaderoTechnologies

Here is the link to the original announcement:

https://blogs.embarcadero.com/syntax-censor-with-goto-and-label-delphi-developer-debate/